# Gradle missingDimensionStrategy with support for debug/release builds

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a library project with 2 flavors defined "flavor1" "flavor2"
In my app gradle file I'm using  missingDimensionStrategy for resolving the flavor

```
 defaultConfig {
    missingDimensionStrategy 'lib', 'flavor1'
}
```

How can i achieve different flavor for debug build and different flavor for release build. 
I want "flavor1" for debug builds and "flavor2" for release builds
I know i can override the missingDimensionStrategy in flavor but not in build type.